# The scriptblock of my powershell jobs is not executed. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, powershell

So, i'm trying to develop a powershell script which which starts multiple background jobs. In each background job a java tool is beeing executed which does some operations on the file system. The script gets run with out any errors but i got no indications on the file system that the scriptblock has been executed. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
     function isRunning {
        param([Alias('n')][string]$name)
        switch((Get-Job -Name $name).State) {
            {$_ -eq 'Running'} {
                "[$($job.Name)] wird noch ausgefuehrt..."
                return $true
            }
            {$_ -eq 'Completed'} {
                "[$($job.Name)] ist abgeschlossen!"
                return $false
            }
        } 
    }
 
    $jar = "... *.jar"
    $trg = "..."
    $src = "..."
    $cfg = "..."
 
    Start-Job -Name "j1" -ScriptBlock   {java -jar args[0] -o args[1] -i args[2] -v args[3] -e ab01 -cfg args[4]} -ArgumentList $jar,$trg,$src,$cfg
    Start-Job -Name "j2" -ScriptBlock {java -jar args[0] -o args[1] -i args[2] -v args[3] -e dg01 -cfg args[4]} -ArgumentList $jar,$trg,$src,$cfg
    Start-Job -Name "j3" -ScriptBlock {java -jar args[0] -o args[1] -i args[2] -v args[3] -e pr01 -cfg args[4]} -ArgumentList $jar,$trg,$src,$cfg   
    Start-Job -Name "j4" -ScriptBlock {java -jar args[0] -o args[1] -i args[2] -v args[3] -e pr00 -cfg args[4]} -ArgumentList $jar,$trg,$src,$cfg
    while((isRunning -n "j1") -or (isRunning -n "j2") -or (isRunning -n "j3") -or (isRunning -n "j4")) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
    }
```

Edit:
Ok, i've refactored the code. It now looks like this:
'''

```
$version = "..."
$jar = "..."
$trg = "..."
$src = "..."
$cfg = "..."

function isRunning {
    param([Alias('n')][string]$name)

    $job = (Get-Job -Name $name)
    switch($job.State) {
        {$_ -eq 'Running'} {
            Write-Host "[$name] wird noch ausgefuehrt..."
            return $true
        }
        {$_ -eq 'Completed'} {
            Write-Host "[$name] ist abgeschlossen!"
            return $false
        }
        {$_ -eq 'Failed' } {
            Write-Host "[$name] ist fehlgeschlagen"
            return $false
        }
    } 
}

function deployToStaging() {
    param([string]$jar,[string]$trg,[string]$src,[string]$version,[string]$cfg)
    Write-Host "Das Deployment auf die Staging Area wird gestartet: "
    Write-Host "$jar`n$trg`n$src`n$version`n$cfg"

    $j1 = Start-Job -Name "j1" -ScriptBlock {java -jar $args[0] -o $args[1] -i $args[2] -v $args[3] -e e1 -cfg $args[4]} -ArgumentList $jar,$trg,$src,$version,$cfg
    $j2 = Start-Job -Name "j2" -ScriptBlock {java -jar $args[0] -o $args[1] -i $args[2] -v $args[3] -e e2 -cfg $args[4]} -ArgumentList $jar,$trg,$src,$version,$cfg
    $j3 = Start-Job -Name "j3" -ScriptBlock {java -jar $args[0] -o $args[1] -i $args[2] -v $args[3] -e e3 -cfg $args[4]} -ArgumentList $jar,$trg,$src,$version,$cfg     
    $j4 = Start-Job -Name "j4" -ScriptBlock {java -jar $args[0] -o $args[1] -i $args[2] -v $args[3] -e e4 -cfg $args[4]} -ArgumentList $jar,$trg,$src,$version,$cfg
    
    while((isRunning -n "j1") -or (isRunning -n "j2") -or (isRunning -n "j3") -or (isRunning -n "j4")) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
    Receive-Job -Job $j1
    Receive-Job -Job $j2
    Receive-Job -Job $j3
    Receive-Job -Job $j4
    Write-Host "Die Staging Area wurde mit den Instanzen bestueckt"
}

function deployToServer() {
    param([string]$trg)
    Write-Host "Das Kopieren auf die Server wird gestartet: "
    Write-Host "$trg"
    $jA = Start-Job -Name "jA" -ScriptBlock {robocopy.exe $args[0] \\server1\e1 /MT /E} -ArgumentList "$trg\e1"
    $jB = Start-Job -Name "jB" -ScriptBlock {robocopy.exe $args[0] \\server1\e2 /MT /E} -ArgumentList "$trg\e2"
    $jC = Start-Job -Name "jC" -ScriptBlock {robocopy.exe $args[0] \\server1\e1 /MT /E} -ArgumentList "$trg\e1"
    $jD = Start-Job -Name "jD" -ScriptBlock {robocopy.exe $args[0] \\server1\e2 /MT /E} -ArgumentList "$trg\e2"
    $jE = Start-Job -Name "jE" -ScriptBlock {robocopy.exe $args[0] \\server1\e1 /MT /E} -ArgumentList "$trg\e1"
    $jF = Start-Job -Name "jF" -ScriptBlock {robocopy.exe $args[0] \\server1\e2 /MT /E} -ArgumentList "$trg\e2"
    while((isRunning -n "jA") -or (isRunning -n "jB") -or (isRunning -n "jC") -or (isRunning -n "jD") -or (isRunning -n "jE") -or (isRunning -n "jF")) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
    Receive-Job -Job $jA
    Receive-Job -Job $jB
    Receive-Job -Job $jC
    Receive-Job -Job $jD
    Receive-Job -Job $jE
    Receive-Job -Job $jF
    Write-Host "e1 und e2 wurden auf die Abnahme Server kopiert"
}
deployToStaging -jar $jar -trg $trg -src $src -version $version -cfg $cfg
deployToCitrix -trg $trg
```

'''

It worked a couple of times, but now it get the following error:

```
In <PathToScript>depl.ps1:45 Zeichen:9
Receive-Job -Job $j1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Picked up JAVA_...e=Europe/Berlin:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
+ PSComputerName        : localhost
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: You should probably check if any of the jobs are in a `Failed` state ;-)

Comment: Also, to see _output_ from your jobs you must request it explicitly, with [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job).

Comment: Try `$args[0]` not `args[0]`. You're missing your dollar sign

Comment: Also: your `isRunningFunction` has _two_ "return values" (outputs): The string with the status information, which is _implicitly_ output ("returned") and the Boolean passed to `return`. Thus, even with `return $false` your function will evaluate to `$true`, because in effect you're doing something like ` if ('foo', $false) { 'true!' }`

Comment: @mklement0: Good point!